# SKPaymentQueue List All Transaction Observers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, storekit

I'm integrating some third-party SDKs into my iOS application. In our app, we have some in-app-purchases available. We are adding our purchase manager as a transaction observer, but I'm wondering if we can find out if these other third-party SDKs are listening to our IAPs and collecting that information. I've searched through the StoreKit API, but I can't find a way to list all the transaction observers. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a public API available for this, but you can always [swizzle](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) the `-[SKPaymentQueue addTransactionObserver:]` method *in your development build* and add a debugger breakpoint (or just perform some logging) in your swizzled implementation of this method in order to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Starting iOS 14, `SKPaymentQueue` class allows [retrieving](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/3578317-transactionobservers) a list of all transaction observers.